# get name of picture?

Tags: c#, winforms, image

```
if(pictureBox4.Image.ToString() == 
    ePRO_Decision_Tool.Properties.Resources.mod_onalertq.ToString())...
```

How to read name of image file loaded in pictureBox (or from resources)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The image loaded in `PictureBox` is just an array of bytes, 
so to find out what is the filename you must fill the `Tag` property of `PictureBox` when any image loaded in it.

Answer (score 5):

An `Image` object only contains the image's binary data. You can manually set the `Tag` property of the `Image` to contain the file name (After you've created the image).

If you load an image to the `PictureBox` using the `Load()` method, that will update the `PictureBox`'s `ImageLocation` property to the file's path.

Then you can use `pictureBox4.ImageLocation` for comparison.

[ImageLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's no way, the Image class doesn't expose where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Images";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG Image(*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP Image(*.bmp)|*.bmp";
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() != "")
    {
        string imagePath = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
        string imagepath = imagePath.ToString();
        imagepath = imagepath.Substring(imagepath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        imagepath = imagepath.Remove(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to get name of picture in picture box:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PictureBox.ImageLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

this Method just working with loading image by `PictureBox.Image.Load(Image Path)`

not working with load image directly from resource 
not working with load image by `PictureBoc.Image = Image.FromFile(Image Path)`
because above methods(except `Image.Load()`) making `Image.ImageLocation` set to `null`

```
PictureBox.Image.Load("Image Path");
string imagepath = PictureBox.Image.ImageLocation.ToString();
                  imagepath = imagepath.Substring(imagepath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                  imagepath = imagepath.Remove(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

get Image name by click

```
 String getImageName = pictureBox1.Name;

        MessageBox.Show(getImageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            OpenFileDialog open =  new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Image Files(* .jpg; * .jpeg; * .png;)|* .jpg; * .jpeg; * .png;";
        if(open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
            
            piturebox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
            String ImageName = Path.GetFileName(open.FileName);
        
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

here is a simple way to get image name from picture box in c#:

```
string imgPath = pictureBox1.ImageLocation; 
string nameImage =imgPath.Substring(imgPath.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
```